# Задача фибоначчи

Tags: swift

Необходимо сделать задачу Фибоначчи через рекурсию.
Я сделал с положительными ответами, но не знаю как сделать что бы они еще были и отрицательные

```
    if n > 1 {
        return fibonacci(n: n - 1) + fibonacci(n: n - 2)
    } else {
        return n
    }
}
```

Comment: А оно для отрицательных не определено

Comment: @KoVadim, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: я знаю, но это уже не числа Фибоначчи.